# Finding Closest Points to a certain Point Given its Coordinates and Maximum Distance - Query Result Undefined using Mongoose with MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've an issue that I wasn't able to solve in some days, even looking at related Stack Overflow Q/A.

I'm developing an application reusing [Scotch's Create a MEAN Stack Google Map App Tutorial by Ahmed Haque](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-mean-apps-with-google-maps-part-i) approach.

I'm trying to implement an application that uses **Google Maps API** to draw `Points`, `LineStrings` and `Polygons` which coordinates are contained in **GeoJson** files that are stored in a **MongoDB** instance.

I'm using `Mongoose` to build the Schema for my data and query my `MongoDB` database.

> I would like to find the closest Points `CP` to a certain Points `P0`
>   given `P0's latitude and longitude` and given a maximum radius
>   `distance` used to find the interested points.

[image]

Given the image over, I would like that, for example, if I insert 2000 (kilometers), my query will find all the points maximum 2000 kilometers away from P0. In this example, it should probably give me P1 and P2.

I was able to do it when I only had Points in my `Mongoose Schema`.

**I had this `Schema` with only markers (Points)**:

```
// Pulls Mongoose dependency for creating schemas
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates a User Schema. 
var MarkerSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    location: {type: [Number], required: true}, // [Long, Lat]
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Indexes this schema in 2dsphere format
MarkerSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('mean-markers', MarkerSchema);
```

**And this was my `Old Query for only Markers`:**

```
var User = require('./model.js');

app.post('/query/', function(req, res) {

        // Grab all of the query parameters from the body.
        var lat = req.body.latitude;
        var long = req.body.longitude;
        var distance = req.body.distance;
        var reqVerified = req.body.reqVerified;

        // Opens a generic Mongoose Query
        var query = User.find({});

        // ...include filter by Max Distance (converting miles to meters)
        if (distance) {

            // Using MongoDB's geospatial querying features
            query = query.where('location').near({
                center: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [long, lat]
                },

                // Converting meters to miles
                maxDistance: distance * 1609.34,
                spherical: true
            });
        }
});
```

It worked really well, and I was able to get close points.

Then, I changed my `Schema` to be more dynamic and also support `Polylines and Polygons`.

**I'm able to insert and draw new Points, Polylines and Polygons with the following `Schema`:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var GeoJSON  = require('geojson');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates a Location Schema.
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
                                    name: {type: String, required: true},
                                    location: {
                                      type: {type : String, required: true},
                                      coordinates : [Schema.Types.Mixed]
                                    },
                                    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
                                    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

LocationSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('mean-locations', LocationSchema);
```

**And this is my `Mongoose Query`:**

```
var GeoObjects = require('./model.js');

app.post('/query/', function(req, res) {

    // Grab all of the query parameters from the body.
    var lat = req.body.latitude;
    var long = req.body.longitude;
    var distance = req.body.distance;

    var query;

    if (distance) {
        query = GeoObjects.find({'location.type':'Point'})
                    .where('location.coordinates').near({
                      center: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [lat, long]
                      },
                      // Converting meters to miles
                      maxDistance: distance * 1609.34,
                      spherical: true
        });
    }

    // Execute Query and Return the Query Results
    query.exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        console.log(users);
        // If no errors, respond with a JSON of all users that meet the criteria
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

`console.log(users);` gives me `undefined.`

Logging query results in my **queryCtrl.js** gives me the following error message:

`name: "MongoError", message: "error processing query: ns=MeanMapApp.mean-locatio…ed error: unable to find index for $geoNear query", waitedMS: 0, ok: 0, errmsg: "error processing query: ns=MeanMapApp.mean-locatio…ed error: unable to find index for $geoNear query"`

**Same with a little variation:**

```
app.post('/query/', function(req, res) {

    // Grab all of the query parameters from the body.
    var lat = req.body.latitude;
    var long = req.body.longitude;
    var distance = req.body.distance;

    console.log(lat,long,distance);

    var points = GeoObjects.find({'location.type':'Point'});

    var loc = parseFloat(points.location.coordinates);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(loc));

    if (distance) {
        var query = points.near(loc, {
                      center: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(long)]
                      },
                      // Converting meters to miles
                      maxDistance: distance * 1609.34,
                      spherical: true
        });
    }
});
```

**This is an example of a marker:**

```
{
  "name": "user01",
  "location": {
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates": [102.0, 0.0]

  }
}
```

**How $near operator works with distance and maxDistance:**

From [Scotch's Making MEAN Apps with Google Maps (Part II) by Ahmed Haque](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-mean-apps-with-google-maps-part-ii)

> MongoDB search parameter $near and its associated properties
>   maxDistance and spherical to specify the range we’re looking to cover.
>   We’re multiplying the distance of our query body by 1609.34, because
>   we want to take our users’ input (in miles) and convert it into the
>   units MongoDB expects (in meters).

1. **Why Am I getting `undefined`?**
2. **Is it possible that this problem is caused by my Schema?**
3. **How can I fix this?**

If you would like to receive some clarifications just post a comment below.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey @AndreaM16. Any chance you have this code on GitHub or something so we can pull it down and take a closer look?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, did you take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this issue.

Essentially, the issue was caused by the schema, since `2dIndex` was referred to a wrong field `(type and coordinates)`.

I solved using the following **Schema**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var GeoJSON  = require('geojson');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var geoObjects = new Schema({
                               name : {type: String},
                               type: {
                                       type: String,
                                       enum: [
                                               "Point",
                                               "LineString",
                                               "Polygon"
                                             ]
                                      },
                                coordinates: [Number],
                                created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
                                updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
geoObjects.pre('save', function(next){
   now = new Date();
   this.updated_at = now;
   if(!this.created_at) {
      this.created_at = now
   }
   next();
});

geoObjects.index({coordinates: '2dsphere'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('geoObjects', geoObjects);
```

And the following **Query**:

```
app.post('/query/', function(req, res) {

        // Grab all of the query parameters from the body.
        var lat = req.body.latitude;
        var long = req.body.longitude;
        var distance = req.body.distance;

        var query = GeoObjects.find({'type':'Point'});

        // ...include filter by Max Distance 
        if (distance) {

            // Using MongoDB's geospatial querying features. 
            query = query.where('coordinates').near({
                center: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [lat, long]
                },

                // Converting meters to miles
                maxDistance: distance * 1609.34,
                spherical: true
            });
        }

        // Execute Query and Return the Query Results
        query.exec(function(err, geoObjects) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            // If no errors, respond with a JSON 
            res.json(geoObjects);
        });
    });
```

I hope it will help someone!

**EDIT**

The schema I put over causes a bit of problems with `LineStrings` and `Polygons`.

Here are correct schemas which allow using `geoQueries`

**linestring-model.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates a LineString Schema.
var linestrings = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required : true},
    geo : {
        type : {type: String,
            default: "LineString"},
        coordinates : Array
    },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
linestrings.pre('save', function(next){
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now
    }
    next();
});

linestrings.index({geo : '2dsphere'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('linestrings', linestrings);
```

**polygon-model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates a Polygon Schema.
var polygons = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required : true},
    geo : {
        type : {type: String,
            default: "Polygon"},
        coordinates : Array
    },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
polygons.pre('save', function(next){
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now
    }
    next();
});

polygons.index({geo : '2dsphere'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('polygons', polygons);
```

**LineString Insert**:

```
{  
    "name" : "myLinestring", 
    "geo" : {
        "type" : "LineString", 
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                17.811, 
                12.634
            ], 
            [
                12.039, 
                18.962
            ], 
            [
                15.039, 
                18.962
            ], 
            [
                29.039, 
                18.962
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**Polygon Insert:**

```
{  
    "name" : "Poly", 
    "geo" : {
        "type" : "Polygon", 
        "coordinates" :  [
                           [ 
                             [25.774, -80.190], [18.466, -66.118], 
                             [32.321, -64.757], [25.774, -80.190] 
                           ]
                         ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand what's beneath all your code, but I know a thing:
If you are using Google's Radar Search, you must take into consideration that

> The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters.

Just take a look at their [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches)

Meaning that if you try with higher radius, results could be Zero

Comment: Hi, I appreciate very much your answer. I'm not using Google's Radar Search, I'm trying to use MongoDb's near and geoNear operators. The fact is that, as I wrote above, when I had a different Mongoose Schema (with only markers) my query worked properly. 
MongoDB search parameter $near and its associated properties maxDistance and spherical to specify the range we’re looking to cover. We’re multiplying the distance of our query body by 1609.34, because we want to take our users’ input (in miles) and convert it into the units MongoDB expects (in meters).

Comment: Regarding your line `console.log(users)` , once I faced a similar problem. The problem was the non-blocking nature of JS, that executed faster the log than the response. In my case,  a promise or a callback solved the problem. Did you try this kind of approach?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but it always get undefined. I think that the problem is kind of caused by my new schema and the near operator.